# for loop String concatenation in jinja

Tags: jinja2

how to store for loop iteration output into variable as comma separated in jinja ?

**Expected output**

*all_servers=test-vm-0,test-vm-1,test-vm-2,test-vm-3*

````
{% set instanceCount = properties["instanceCount"] %}

{% set all_servers = [] %}
{% for vmIndex in range(instanceCount) %}
{% do all_servers.append({{ env["deployment"] }}-vm-{{ vmIndex }}) %}
{% endfor%}
{% all_servers|join(', ') %}```
````

Comment: Do you want to store into a variable or output to the template result?

Comment: Store it in a variable and pass it as metadata key/ value pair from the same jinja file. This jinja file is used with gloud deployment manager

Comment: Does `{% set all_servers=','.join(all_servers) %}` work?

Comment: Let me check, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  - key: all_servers
    {% set delimiter = joiner(",") %}
    value: {% for vmIndex in range(properties["instanceCount"]) -%}
      {{- delimiter() }}{{ env["deployment"] }}--vm-{{ vmIndex -}}
    {%- endfor %}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Regular Python concatenation should do the trick:

```
{% set all_servers=','.join(all_servers) %}
```